# Ordenamiento con mongoose no es el esperado

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy obteniendo los documentos paginados de un modelo con "aggregate" de mongoDB, el problema es que cuando quiero hacer un ordenamiento descendiente por la fecha de creacion, me regresa mal la paginacion, por ejemplo, si tengo seis registros con las siguientes fechas

"2020/03/22 00:10:00",
"2020/03/22 00:09:00",
"2020/03/22 00:08:00",
"2020/03/22 00:07:00",
"2020/03/22 00:06:00",
"2020/03/22 00:05:00"

y estoy obteniendo de tres en tres, el resultado esperado es

Pagina #1
"2020/03/22 00:10:00",
"2020/03/22 00:09:00",
"2020/03/22 00:08:00",

Pagina #2
"2020/03/22 00:07:00",
"2020/03/22 00:06:00",
"2020/03/22 00:05:00"

sin embargo mongoose me regresa

Pagina #1
"2020/03/22 00:07:00",
"2020/03/22 00:06:00",
"2020/03/22 00:05:00",

Pagina #2
"2020/03/22 00:10:00",
"2020/03/22 00:09:00",
"2020/03/22 00:08:00"

mi codigo esta de la siguiente manera

```
Product.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: File.collection.name,
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'product',
                as: 'files'
            }
        },
        {$match: filtersCleaned},
        {$skip: skip},
        {$limit: this.limit},
        {$sort: {createdAt: -1}}
    ]);
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Si mueves la etapa `$sort` antes de la etapa `$skip`, hace alguna diferencia?

Comment: ¿Y tu colección, dónde está?

Comment: @MauricioContreras increible pero cierto jaja, el solo mover el sort antes del skip soluciono el problema, muchas gracias!!